# Counting elements of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to count each element of a 2d array, but for some reason I'm doing something wrong:

```
    int[][] array = {{2, 3, 2}, {2, 2}};
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int k = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
```

Comment: Look at your inner loop. Is it traversing the second dimension of your array?

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop should count the elements of each array element by accessing them via `array[i]`:

```
int[][] array = {{2, 3, 2}, {2, 2}};
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < array[i].length; k++) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could also omit the inner loop and simply do `counter += array[i].length`.